# Regarding passing php variable to another page via link

Tags: php

I want to pass a php variable, which is store in $row['ID'] to another page so i can execute my sql query with the passed variable.

I have this line of code with me

```
<?php echo ("<td>" . "<a href='http://localhost/kinhock/delete.php?ID=$row['ID']'>" 
. "Delete" . "<td>"); ?>
```

However i am getting syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)

I am not clear about the double quote and single quote position. Is there any other way to pass my php variable instead of using this?

Comment: what's the format of ID? Might it need to be URL encoded?

Answer (score 1):

It will be like

```
echo "<td><a href='http://localhost/kinhock/delete.php?ID=".$row['ID']."'>Delete<td>";
```

Comment: Omg i works like charm!! Thanks to all of you buddy, everytime i have something stuck in php programming, I will always seek help from here and it always gave the solution. You guys are awesome, especially you Gautam3164, love u!

Answer (score 1):

When you have an array variable with a quoted string, you have to put a block around it to get it to interpolate properly.  Your entire string can be rendered like this, just using interpolation:

```
echo "<td><a href='http://localhost/kinhock/delete.php?ID={$row['ID']}'>Delete<td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
echo "<td><a href='http://localhost/kinhock/delete.php?ID=".$row['ID']."'>Delete<td>";
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

echo doesn't use (), it is like this

```
echo "<td>" . "<a href='http://localhost/kinhock/delete.php?ID=".$row['ID'].">" . "Delete" . "<td>");
```

Comment: or simply, use print instead of echo

Comment: So you didn't actually try to answer the question, just gave a misleading and wrong comment?